# Storing multiple values in one column

Tags: python, sqlite

I am designing a web application that has users becoming friends with other users. I am storing the users info in a database using sqlite3. 
I am brainstorming on how I can keep track on who is friends with whom.
What I am thinking so far is; to make a column in my database called Friendships where I store the various user_ids( integers) from the user's friends.
I would have to store multiple integers in one column...how would I do that?
Is it possible to store a python list in a column?

I am also open to other ideas on how to store the friendship network information in my database....

The application runs through FLASK

Comment: Typically many-to-many relations is implemented using  2-column table (from, to). You might have multiple 'to's for one 'from' and vice versa

Comment: You want an [`Associative Entity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) where the PRIMARY KEY is both entries combined.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here is called a "many-to-many" relationship. Rather than making a "Friendships" column, you can make a "Friendship" table with two columns: `user1` and `user2`. Entries in this table indicate that `user1` has friended `user2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to store a list as a string into an sql column.

However, you should instead be looking at creating a Friendships table with primary keys being the user and the friend.
So that you can call the friendships table to pull up the list of friends.

Otherwise, I would suggest looking into a Graph Database, which handles this kind of things well too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to organize correct storage of data you should know more about relative databases. I recommend you to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) first of all. With some normalization it would perform better (some operations on db will be much more simplier).

As mentioned before you should make another table with friendships to perform first normal form. It would be much easier for you to perform modification of relationships.